# CSS footer not displaying in the centre

Tags: html, css

im using this CSS for my website footer:

what would be the best way to make it display in the centre of the page. my website is responsive so they automatically go underneath each other when the screen is made smaller but when the screen is larger they are more to the left than the right.

i have created a fiddle here so you can also see the html:http://jsfiddle.net/x4A4B/

any help would be much appreciated

```
#footer {
    width:100%;
    min-height:500px;
    position:relative;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    border-top:4px solid #F36F25;
    background-color:#666666;
    color:#EEEEEE;
}
#footer-inner {
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    height:inherit;
}
#footer-top {
    width:100%;
    padding-top:10px;
    border-bottom:2px #EEEEEE solid;
    display:block;
}
#footer-left {
    width: 290px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    border-right:1px #EEEEEE solid;
    vertical-align:top;
}
#footer-middle {
    width: 294px; /* Account for margins + border values */
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-right:1px #EEEEEE solid;
    vertical-align:top;
}
#footer-right {
    width: 270px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
#footer-bottom {
    margin-top:5px;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, the whole thing is a footer? Usually a footer is just the Copyright

Comment: no its a large footer with 3 columns. i want the 3 columns to display inline, all next to each other and in the centre of the page

Comment: Are the columns supposed to be side-by-side?

Comment: Ah, I see when the windows gets too small they move underneath each other, you can fix that by setting a min-width on body of the page.

Comment: no - i want them to display underneath each other when the screen is smaller but when the screen is larger the 3 columns are displaying more to the left than in the centre

Comment: Okay, I understand. Centering them would be a lot easier if they stayed a fixed width, though. I'll try to center them as it is now.

Comment: So, when you resize this jsfiddle screen, they stick left. They dont get centered?

Comment: Set a min-width on #footer to simulate a large screen and see what he's talking about. I set it to 1600px and the footer is all the way to the left. I know how to perfectly center it dynamically, but it will require some jQuery, is that alright? Normally, it just takes css, but I need jQuery to listen for the width changes.

Comment: what should i set the min-width to and do i keep the width there or get rid of it ?

Comment: responsive solution .. querying width screen by @media ..

Comment: Ugh, I'm about to do it, I just can't figure out how to get my function to return a number in pixels. Like right now it's returning -500, I need it to return -500px.

Comment: im not too sure on that part - not great with jquery :)

Answer (score 0):

are you talking about your Copyright label?
if I understood correctly, you need `text-align:center;` in `footer-bottom` as in

```
#footer-bottom {
margin-top:5px;
padding: 15px 15px;
font-size:12px;
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: i want the 3 columns to display centre of the page - if the screen is too big they display more to the left of the page

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need something like this regarding lay-out:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
        Content goes here
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
        Content goes here
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        Content goes here
    </div> 
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper{
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   left: 20.00%;
   width: 60.00%;
}
.left{
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   left: 0%;
   width: 32.00%;
}
.middle{
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   left: 1.50%;
   width: 32.00%;
}
.right{
   position: relative;
   float: right;
   right: 0%;
   width: 33.00%;
}
```

Of course, you'll have to fill the structure with your content, and modify the margins to completely suit your needs, but I think you'll manage to do that. This example is just to get the idea.

See it in action here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NZktT/)

Comment: i want to keep the columns so they display under each other when the screen is too small as my website is responsive

Comment: ive added: position: relative;
 float: left;
 left: 20.00%;
 width: 60.00%; to #footer-inner and that has worked, however as the screen gets smaller - the 3 columns start to go underneath each other but the background on #footer height doesnt get any bigger

Comment: I think you should add this to the bottom of `#footer`: `<div class="clearfix"></div>`, and in your CSS do the following: `.clearfix { clear: both; }`. Does that work as you'd expect?

Comment: On the topic of responsive design, this link might help: http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/